# More formal word for "rich" used in the sarcastic sense

Tags: single-word-requests

When someone has said something incredibly hypocritical, you might respond, ***"[That's rich](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/That%27s+rich!)."***  This helps you express how disgusted you are about the hypocrisy.

What's a formal alternative to ***rich*** used in this way?

Example of how I would like to use the word:

> It is __________ (adj) [or, it is the height of _________ (noun)] for the school to claim that such-and-so change to the student's 504 plan was made based on the parents' input.  In fact, the parents had strenuously objected to the change for the following reasons: ....

But *hypocrisy* isn't strong enough.

Comment: *Hypocrites* is what the Scribes and the Pharisees were. I can't think of anything much stronger than that!

Comment: 'Precious', or the stronger 'priceless', are sometimes used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - With *priceless*, it isn't clear enough that I'm making a strong criticism, but I looked it up in the idioms dictionary that J O S H pointed me to, and found *hilarious*.  Hmm.  Probably not formal enough.

Comment: @WS2 - But saying "that's a hilarious statement" feels stronger to me than "that statement is the height of hypocrisy."  I want to show the feeling of bitter disgust.

Comment: 'That's ludicrous' is stronger still, but is not anti-hypocrisy specific.

Comment: "It’s very telling, yet equally typical that the school would dare to claim that the change to the student's 504 plan was made based on the parents' input.  The only possible connection between that input and the change was an inverse one in that the school seemingly did exactly the opposite of what the parents had suggested and it’s the height of spin-doctoring and the nadir of transparency for the school to now characterize this inverted connection as “being based on” instead of “being in spite of” the parents’ input."

Comment: I don't know how formal it is, but the school's insistence that the parents demanded something they actually opposed sounds like _doublethink_ to me.  Also more than a little _Kafkaesque_.

Comment: I got a new one -- when I have time I'll make it an answer.  *Cynical*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe I got it:

> It is a *cruel joke* for the school to claim etc.

Comment: Best idea so far, in my view. I don't see how things like *precious* *priceless* and *hilarious* etc fit the bill at all. They are just mild sarcasm - nowhere as strong as *hypocrisy*.

Answer (score 1):

"Disingenuous" is what you're looking for, I think.

M-W:

> not truly honest or sincere : giving the false appearance of being honest or sincere

Answer (score 0):

How about *absurd beyond belief*?

M-W:

> [*absurd*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absurd):
>   ridiculously unreasonable, unsound, or incongruous

Your example:

> It is *absurd beyond belief* for the school to claim that such-and-so
>   change to the student's 504 plan was made based on the parents' input.
>   In fact, the parents had strenuously objected to the change for the
>   following reasons: ...

Comment: This is promising.

Comment: But not necessarily anti-hypocrisy the way 'rich' is.

Comment: The example is not so much about hypocrisy as it is about the school claiming something that is ridiculously intrue. Where's the hypocrisy? Hypocrisy and falsehood / disingenuousness are two different things. You're off base.

Comment: Richard Kayser is right. If the parents objecting to the plan clearly outnumbered the parents supporting the plan, the school is  simply being dishonest (although strictly speaking it may be basing its decision on *some* parents' input). I might just use 'dishonest' (or possibly 'disingenuous') preceded by an intensifying adverb like 'absurdly'.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you're still looking for answers but i mainly am basing my input off of related words and I think what you're offended by is the amount of **entitlement** so I looked up some synonyms and there is impudence. Condescension. the term "adding insult to injury" comes to mind. indignity. blind arrogance. i'm sorry if you don't like any of these I just thought I'd throw some suggestions out there.